# How to make hg serve drop root priveleges after launch?

Tags: linux, networking, mercurial, privileges, hgserve

I have a HG repository on one of my computers. I sometimes develop on this machine, other times I use my laptop. I run the "hg serve" mini webserver to transfer changesets to and from my laptop.

The problem is that I have to be root in order for "hg serve" to open the network ports. When I then push a change from my laptop which creates new files, they are owned by root. And the next time I want to commit something when working on the computer serving the repositories I don't have permission to some of the file. I could do

```
sudo hg commit
```

but that just seems excessive and annoying.

Is there any way to launch "hg serve" have it open the network ports, then drop root priveleges when manipulating files?

Comment: Why not just run `hg serve` on ports above 1024 (with user privileges)?

Comment: To be honest I forgot that ports above 1024 didn't need sudo rights to open, but hg serve still doesn't work when running without sudo rights. Must be some other reason. I just assumed (wrongly) it was the permissions for the ports that was the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It won't drop privileges.  If you're running a repo just for you, you should use ssh:// URLs rather than `hg serve` and spare yourself the hassle of running a server at all.  If you're running it for more than just you, you should have nginx or apache listening on port 443 (or 80) and proxying to a production-grade wsgi container like gunicorn listining on a high-numbered port.

From `hg help serve`:

```
You can use this
for ad-hoc sharing and browsing of repositories. It is recommended to use
a real web server to serve a repository for longer periods of time.
```